# android studio add markers to google maps from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

In my android app I'm trying to add several markers from sqlite to a MapsActivity. I created a do-while cycle for getting all the cities in sqlite table and convert all cities in coordinates (lat, long), but there's something in error. Can you help me?

---MapsActivity.java---

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
DatabaseHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng ruvo = new LatLng(-45, 123);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ruvo).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ruvo));
    displayCities();
}

public void onSearch(View view) {
    EditText textCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textCity);
    String location = textCity.getText().toString();
    List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker pointed"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

}

public void displayCities() {
    List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;
    Cursor database = myDb.display();

    if (database.getCount()== 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    //string array of all cities
    database.moveToFirst();
    String[] cities = new String[database.getCount()];
    int n = 0;
    do {
        cities[n] = database.getString(3).toString();
        n=n+1;
    } while (database.moveToNext());

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(cities[n], 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker pointed"));
    }

}
```

---DaTabaseHelper.java---

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
//VERY IMPORTANT: CursorAdapter needs exactly "_id" column, as written here
public static final String COL_1 = "_id";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "CITY";

public ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            + COL_2 + " TEXT , " + COL_3 + " TEXT , " + COL_4 + " TEXT );");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor selected(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_1, DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor c = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, DatabaseHelper.COL_1 + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String city) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentValues = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    ContentValues.put(COL_3, surname);
    ContentValues.put(COL_4, city);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, ContentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

//method for select query
public Cursor display() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}


public boolean UpdateData(String id, String name, String surname, String city) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentValues = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    ContentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    ContentValues.put(COL_3, surname);
    ContentValues.put(COL_4, city);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, ContentValues, "_id = ?", new String[] {id});
    return true;
}

public Integer DeleteData (String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[] {id});
}


}
```

**EDIT: I add the error in logcat**

beginning of crash

> 06-28 12:17:13.332 2915-2915/com.example.android.sqlite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.android.sqlite, PID: 2915
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.android.sqlite.DatabaseHelper.display()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.example.android.sqlite.MapsActivity.displayCities(MapsActivity.java:76)
>   at com.example.android.sqlite.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:51)
>   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
>   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.be.a(SourceFile:82)
>   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fb.run(Unknown Source)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   06-28 12:17:15.410 2915-2915/com.example.android.sqlite I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2915 SIG: 9

Comment: Specify the error.

Comment: Hi, I have just added it..